# Issue on Stop/Prevent Tab Changing on Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using JavaScript on an ASp.net web application and I have a button which is supposed to display an image on the page on click which is working but It also change the Tab element from tab 2 to tab 0 index!

Here is the JavaScript and Asp.net code which I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var baseUrl = document.URL.split("WebForms/")[0];
     function openImageDoc(filePath, titleName) {
        var newUrl = baseUrl + filePath;
        window.open(newUrl, titleName, 'width=900,height=800,scrollbars=1');
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="RiskMapDisplay" runat="server" style="margin-left: 734px" 
  OnClientClick="openImageDoc('Images/riskmap.jpg', 'RiskMap')" 
  Text="Risk Matrix" CausesValidation="False" TabIndex="3" />
```

Can you please let me know how I can stop tabbing with this or what it may cause this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var baseUrl = document.URL.split("WebForms/")[0];
 function openImageDoc(filePath, titleName) {
    var newUrl = baseUrl + filePath;
    window.open(newUrl, titleName, 'width=900,height=800,scrollbars=1');
    return false;
}
```

```
<asp:Button ID="RiskMapDisplay" runat="server" style="margin-left: 734px" 
  OnClientClick="return openImageDoc('Images/riskmap.jpg', 'RiskMap')" 
  Text="Risk Matrix" CausesValidation="False" TabIndex="3" />
```

Adding `return false;` to the function stops the button from performing its normal function, which in this case would be a postback to the server.

Mark as answered if it works.

Comment: Hi Mandar Patil, thanks for reply but the issue still remains!